# Using Windows API commands to close child windows

Tags: windows

--Update 2/29/12 Thanks all for the help. I have gone ahead with calling BringWindowToTop() before using SendMessage() to get the desired behavior. If you have a better method please feel free to post here but otherwise I consider the issue closed. Thanks again!

--Update 12/9/11 Last night I wrote a crummy little C# project to demonstrate.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        //kill the windows which have our documents open, namely EXCEL!
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel");
        //find excel
        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            //hunt down its children
        U     List<IntPtr> Children = new List<IntPtr>();
            Children = GetChildWindows(p.MainWindowHandle);                
            foreach (IntPtr child in Children)
            {
                //see if the child has our document
                foreach (string xo in is_opened_files)
                {                        
                    if (GetText(child).Contains(xo))
                    {
                        //kill excel's children (oh noes!)
                        SendMessage((uint)child, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //clean up the list of files we opened
        is_opened_files.Clear();
    }
```

The behavior changes depending on the order of the list object Children<>. If the order of the list matches the Z Order of the child window, meaning the first Child to be evaluated is also the topmost childwindow, then the child accepts and processes the SendMessage() command to close as expected. If you change the order of Children<> so that the items are processed in a different order, only the topmost childwindow closes.

The point being, I guess, that it seems like only the topmost child will accept and process this command but I cannot find any documentation as to why or even that we should be expecting this behavior at all.

--end update 12/9/11

I'm just going to break into the details. I'm new to using the Windows API, but I think I understand at least how to make the calls correctly.

I am working with an application built in Powerbuilder 11.5. I am reading some blobs from a database and writing them to files in the temp directory, then using ShellExecuteExW to launch the file. The user may launch multiple files or no files. The files may be a mix of .xls(x), .doc(x), .pdf, and various text or image formats (.txt, .jpg...etc)

So the user can open the documents in their respective application, but then when they close my application I need to tell all the documents I've opened for them to close as well.

For now, I'm enumerating all the window handles, classes and titles on the system, then searching the titles for the name of a document I have opened for them. I may also verify that the ClassName is something I'm interested in. I'm using FindWindowEx, GetWindowText and GetClassName for this.

Once I find my file name I grab the associated handle for the window and then use SendMessage with the WM_CLOSE parameter value to tell the window to close.

This works great when dealing with SDI applications like acrobat reader, MS Word, MS Paint, etc. This fails miserably when working with Excel.

The issue seems to be that if a user has multiple documents open in Excel, the child will only close if it is the topmost child window.

I have searched and searched and cannot find where this behavior is coming from. If I call BringWindowToTop immediately before SendMessage then the windows close as expected. Otherwise they just remain. Microsoft documentation seems to imply that sending wm_close to a window is the proper way to close it, regardless of its status as a child/parent or Z order.

I have also tried using GetAncestor with the GA_PARENT parameter value to get the Child's Parent window, then use SendMessage to notify the Parent window that it should perform WM_MDIDESTROY on the child window in question. Same results as if I SendMessage WM_CLOSE directly to the child. The topmost child will close, but that's it.

What am I missing?

Here is some sample code:

```
//assume I have already executed the code to
//get the window handle by searching the title for my file name

//define some constants
CONSTANT long WM_MDIDESTROY = 545
CONSTANT long WM_MDIACTIVATE = 546
CONSTANT long WM_CLOSE = 16

//lul_hWnd = handle to child window, assume we have it already
//lul_parenthWnd = handle to immediate ancestor of childWindow

uLong lul_hWnd, lul_parenthWnd
long ll_null

setnull(ll_null)

//Example 1
//this works when the window is an SDI app or an MDI with maximized children
if IsWindow(lul_hWnd) then
    SendMessage(lul_hWnd,WM_CLOSE,ll_null, ll_null) 
end if

//Example 2
//this seems to work with most instances, including for an MDI with multiple children
if IsWindow(lul_hWnd) then
    BringWindowToTop(lul_hWnd)
    SendMessage(lul_hWnd,WM_CLOSE,ll_null,ll_null)
end if

//Example 3
//The result of this code seems to be the same as the first example
if IsChild(lul_parenthWnd,lul_hWnd) then
    SendMessage(lul_parenthWnd, WM_MDIDESTROY, lul_hWnd, ll_null)
end if

//Example 4
//Adding a preceeding MDIACTIVATE message seems to have no effect
if IsChild(lul_parenthWnd,lul_hWnd) then
    SendMessage(lul_parenthWnd, WM_MDIACTIVATE, lul_hWnd, ll_null)
    SendMessage(lul_parenthWnd, WM_MDIDESTROY, lul_hWnd, ll_null)
end if
```

Also, if you have any ideas on how to better do this I'm all ears. I just really don't want to get into managing OLE servers for all the different applications the users may launch with these files.

Thanks for your consideration and happy coding :)

*edit - I originally had links to all the MSDN library entries for the functions and parameters I listed here, but I was forced to remove them because I'm new here.

Hers's a root link: [MSDN WinAPI documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff657751%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't think there is any reliable way of doing this.  For one thing, you're risking inadvertently closing something the user is working on which just happens to have the same name as one of the documents you opened.  I think it would be preferable to just leave the documents open, and let the user close them.  IMO this would be the behaviour the user would both expect and prefer.

Comment: There is no uniform way of doing this. (Think about it: How would somebody tell *your* program to close a specific database?)

Comment: There is no uniform way of doing this. You will have to handle it on an application-by-application basis. Excel works one way, Firefox works another way, etc. You may be better off trying to use the Excel object model.

Comment: Educated guess: I suspect you'll find that when you click on the close button of a child window, Windows automatically brings that window to the top before sending it WM_CLOSE.  So the behaviour you're observing has no effect under normal circumstances.  Perhaps you can replicate this somehow, perhaps by sending WM_MDIACTIVATE before WM_CLOSE.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it myself, but it looks like [ShellExecuteEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would do the same thing as ShellExecute, but give you a process handle which you could use with [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

However, I'd agree with Harry's comment that you're killing any other documents the user may have opened inside one of these multi-document apps. While I may agree that fantasy football pools should be shut down, I'm not sure it's good form if your app does it. (And when the CFO calls you in because you trashed the financial statements he worked on through the night and are due to be published in minutes, don't say we didn't warn you.)

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: `TerminateProcess()` is a very bad idea and can lead to even more data loss, and possible corruption than just random `WM_CLOSE` messages.

Comment: @Deanna: The whole design is bad. WM_CLOSE can be defeated with a simple "Do you want to save?" "Cancel." However, I'm sure you're formulating a superior solution to them all; we look forward.

Comment: @Babbleon Then Raymond is on the money, IMHO: there is no magic bullet, you're likely going to need to customize your approach for each app.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, Keys wParam, Int32
lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "EnumDesktopWindows", ExactSpelling = false,
CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop, EnumDelegate
lpEnumCallbackFunction, IntPtr lParam);

public delegate bool EnumDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);

// returns a list with handles who you need
public static List<IntPtr> getVisibleProcesses()
{
    var handle = new List<IntPtr>();

    EnumDelegate filter = delegate(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
    {
        StringBuilder strbTitle = new StringBuilder(255);
        int nLength = GetWindowText(hWnd, strbTitle, strbTitle.Capacity + 1);
        string strTitle = strbTitle.ToString();

        // adds to list, tasks who appear in the taskbar and contains the string "Excel"
        if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd) && strTitle.Contains("Excel"))
            handle.Add(hWnd);

        return true;
    };
    EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr.Zero, filter, IntPtr.Zero);

    return handle;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;

    foreach (IntPtr h in getVisibleProcesses())
        PostMessage(h, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you read the question properly.  All that your code does is send a WM_CLOSE message, which the OP was already doing.

Comment: "The problem is that when the window you SendMessage() to is behind another child in the same MDI, then the window seems to ignore the message."

With my code there is no problem with the above..

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the OPs problem using his code?  If so, that's great; but it would have been better, rather than just posting your code, to identify what exactly makes your code work when his doesn't.